# How to show up to 2 decimal in a 12 digit string

Tags: java

I have a string of 12 digit coming n string format 000000003625 i want to make it 36.25   how i will do please help me

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    //Parse our JSON response 
     JSONParser j = new JSONParser();

     JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)j.parse(line); 

     String   resCode  = (String) jsonObject.get("RSP_CODE");
```

here i am getting in string format

Comment: Create a BigDecimal from the string and then divide it by 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the string to a number and divide by 100 (floating point):

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("000000003625") / 100.0;
```

And format the result:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String result = df.format(d);
```

Or if floating point imprecision could be an issue, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for the parsing and division, then format the resulting `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("000000003625")
                        .divide(new BigDecimal(100));
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String result = df.format(bd);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Hus5aI)

Comment: Thank u so much,I used bigDecimal and got the response

Answer (score 4):

This may be what you need:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("000000003625").divide(new BigDecimal(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to long and then divide it by 100

Comment: Max value of an Integer is: 2,147,483,647 which is 10 digits, not 12.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear, you want to show up 36.25 if the input string is 000000003625. Here is the code that you may want to use.

```
String val = "000000003625";
Float i = Float.parseFloat(val);
System.out.println(i / 100);
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's probably just because it's float. When you've got a more precise version (double) and a completely precise object that works with Strings (BigDecimal) it seems odd to use float.